# I cannot import fontawesome icons in my react project. (reactv6)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome

This is my code snippet.

```js
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome"; 
import { faQuestionCircle, faExclamationCircle, faCog,} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

 <div className="action-btn">
        <FontAwesomeIcon className="icon-block" icon={faQuestionCircle} />
        <FontAwesomeIcon className="icon-block" icon={faExclamationCircle} />
        <FontAwesomeIcon className="icon-block" icon={faCog} />
</div>
```

I installed the required packages yet I received the error "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome' "

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix for v6 we need to

```
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@latest
```

Refer https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/use-with/react/